# How to make reversed for loop with array index as a start/end point in Kotlin?

Tags: for-loop, kotlin, reverse

now i'm trying to make reversed for a loop.The simple way of reverse for is 
for(i in start downTo end)

but,what if I use array as a start/end point?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can loop from the last index calculated by taking `size - 1` to 0 like so:

```
for (i in array.size - 1 downTo 0) {
    println(array[i])
}
```

Even simpler, using the [`lastIndex`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last-index.html) extension property:

```
for (i in array.lastIndex downTo 0) {
    println(array[i])
}
```

Or you could take the [`indices`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/indices.html) range and reverse it:

```
for (i in array.indices.reversed()) {
    println(array[i])
}
```

Comment: ok, i never thought about that before.it works.thanks for the help sir

Comment: About the last one, the one with `reversed()`, wouldn't it be slower, as it will reverse the array first and then loop through it?

Comment: If you look at the bytecode, it actually translates to simple index iteration. There's no need to reverse the array to walk down the indexes.

Comment: 0

This is very helpful. I hate the .. doesn't include downTo. I also hate the until is not inclusive, and downTo is inclusive, but there is no upTo or downUntil to make it symmetrical. Just feels really weird and has to be careful with the final index.

Comment: Last one is very nice!

Answer (score 20):

Additionally to the first [answer from zsmb13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51917909/5966775), some other variants.

Using [`IntProgression.reversed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/reversed.html):

```
for (i in (0..array.lastIndex).reversed())
    println("On index $i the value is ${array[i]}")
```

or using [`withIndex()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-index.html) together with [`reversed()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reversed.html)

```
array.withIndex()
        .reversed()
        .forEach{ println("On index ${it.index} the value is ${it.value}")}
```

or the same using a for loop:

```
for (elem in array.withIndex().reversed())
    println("On index ${elem.index} the value is ${elem.value}")
```

or if the index is not needed

```
for (value in array.reversed())
    println(value)
```

Answer (score 3):

A very clean way in kotlin:

```
for (i in array.indices.reversed()) {
    println(array[i])
}
```

Comment: Kindly do not put code only answer. Putting a description to the code helps beginners understand the context.

Answer (score 1):

Just leaving it here in case someone needs it

I created an extension function:

```
public inline fun <T> Collection<T>.forEachIndexedReversed(action: (index: Int, T) -> Unit): Unit {
    var index = this.size-1
    for (item in this.reversed()) action(index--, item)
}
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel bro.

Answer (score 0):

For performance optimal implementation you can use this:

```
inline fun <T> Array<T>.forEachReverse(action: (T) -> Unit) {
    var index = lastIndex
    while (index >= 0) {
        action(this[index])
        index--
    }
}
```

It does not create another instance and still uses classical forEach syntax, so you can drop in replace and also is inlined.

For list the same:

```
inline fun <T> List<T>.forEachReverse(action: (T) -> Unit) {
    var index = size - 1
    while (index >= 0) {
        action(this[index])
        index--
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.reversed().forEachIndexed { index, data ->
    action(data)
}
```

Test:

```
val list = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
list.reversed().forEachIndexed { index, data ->
    println("$index $data")
}
println("---")
list.withIndex().reversed().forEach {
    println("${it.index} ${it.value}")
}

0 e
1 d
2 c
3 b
4 a
---
4 e
3 d
2 c
1 b
0 a
```